# php xhr request works on local but not on server

Tags: php, ajax, progress, iis-10, jqxhr

I've trying to create a progress bar while the script executes. It works fine when I test in Visual Studio, but when I put it on a server, it won't work.
Is there some php or IIS setting that might be disabling this? It only fires at the end of the script execution.
I've also tried multiple different ways of doing the XHR request.
I've used xhrfields, xhr on it's own and ya... again works in development, but on the server, nope.

My php file

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $response = array();
    $links = array();
    $progress = 0;
    $progressFinal = 10;
    echo json_encode(array('progress' => $progress));
    ob_implicit_flush(true);
    ob_end_flush();
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        sleep(2);
        $progress++;
        echo json_encode(array('progress' => (round(($progress / $progressFinal) * 100))));
        flush();
        ob_flush();
    }
}
```

my js file

```
$.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        xhrFields:
        {
            onprogress: function (e) {
                var thisResponse, response = e.currentTarget.response;
                if (lastResponseLen === false) {
                    thisResponse = response;
                    lastResponseLen = response.length;
                }
                else {
                    thisResponse = response.substring(lastResponseLen);
                    lastResponseLen = response.length;
                }

                jsonResponse = JSON.parse(thisResponse);
                $('#emrcp').html('- ' + jsonResponse.progress + '%');
            }
        },
        success: function (text) {
            $('#emrcBtn').html('Sent!');
            for (var i = 0; i < response.links.length; i++) {
                $('#emlStat' + response.links[i].fam_id).html('Sent...');
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Successful flashing can depend on a lot of factors, do a bit of research into the issue - https://www.google.com/search?q=php+flush+iis+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: could you check console log for more detail?

Comment: @CBroe Thanks so much! I had given up, but your suggestion helped me find the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened to be my IIS settings like I figured. I just need to add responseBufferLimit="0" to my webconfig for php and FastCGI.

Answer (score 0):

```
//first convert your js file into php file like js.php
//and include it in your project

<?php include "js.php"; ?>

//like this
//then
//code this in js.php file

let base_url = "<?= "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>";

//then use it in ajax url like this 


$.ajax({
        url: base_url+"test.php",
        type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        xhrFields:
        {
           // your code
        },
        success: function (text) {
         // your code
        }
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. The more I fight with it, the more I think it's something to do with IIS or PHP, but I have seen a few comments of people saying they changed some kind of network setting, but didn't say what exactly they changed.

Comment: you need to get base url of the domain you are working with either local or live to send the ajax request otherwise it will not work

Comment: From my research it seems that because it's not downloading a huge script, but just executing a script that it isn't possible this way, maybe due to some caching or something. Not sure, but looks like either creating a second request to get progress or websockets seem to be the only answer.